# Using match with user defined types in PL Racket

Tags: racket

The following PL code does not work under `#lang pl`:

*Edited code according to Alexis Kings answer*

```
(define-type BINTREE
  [Leaf Number]
  [Node BINTREE BINTREE])

(: retrieve-leaf : BINTREE -> Number)
(define (retrieve-leaf btree)
  (match btree
  [(Leaf number) number])
```

What i'd like to achieve is as follows:

1. Receive a BINTREE as input
2. Check whether the tree is simply a leaf
3. Return the leaf numerical value

This might be a basic question but how would I go about solving this?

---

**EDIT:** The above seems to work if `cases` is used instead of `match`.
Why is that?

Comment: Is this plai-typed or Typed Racket?

Comment: This is PL, a variant of Typed Racket.

Comment: Oh! Is this @EliBarzilay's class?

Comment: No, not his class. But our syllabus is based on his course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, `match` and `cases` are two similar but separate
things.  The first is used for general Racket values, and the second is
used for things that you defined with `define-type`.  Unfortunately,
they don't mix well in either direction, so if you have a defined type
then you need to use `cases`.

As for the reason for that, it's kind of complicated...  One thing is
that the `pl` language was made well before `match` was powerful enough
to deal with arbitrary values conveniently.  It does now, but it cannot
be easily tweaked to do what cases does: the idea behind `define-type`
is to make programming simple by making it mandatory to use *just*
`cases` for such values --- there are no field accessors, no predicates
for the variants (just for the whole type), and certainly no mutation.
Still, it is possible to do anything you need with just `cases`.  If you
read around, the core idea is to mimic disjoint union types in HM
languages like ML and Haskell, and with only `cases` pattern matching
available, many functions are easy to start since there's a single way
to deal with them.

`match` and Typed Racket got closer to being able to do these things,
but it's still not really powerful enough to do all of that --- which is
why `cases` will stay separate from `match` in the near future.

As a side note, this is in contrast to what I want --- I know that this
is often a point of confusion, so I'd love to have just `match` used
throughout.  Maybe I'll break at some point and hack things so that
`cases` is also called `match`, and the contents of the branches would
be used to guess if you really need the real `match` or the `cases`
version.  But that would really be a crude hack.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, but your `match` syntax isn't correct. It should look like this:

```
(: retrieve-leaf : BINTREE -> Number)
(define (retrieve-leaf btree)
  (match btree
    [(Leaf number) number]))
```

The match pattern clauses must be inside the `match` form. Additionally, `number` is just a binding, not a procedure, so it doesn't need to be in parens.